# Problems Enabling Push Notifications on AWS Mobile Hub

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-mobilehub

I am having a problem "enabling" Push Notifications on AWS Mobile Hub for my app. I want to enable it for my iOS app, so I went on and uploaded my Universal Apple Certificate, and then selected my topics. I didn't enter any info for Android.

What happens is when I click Save Changes, it seems as if it's not working. Because when I click on the Push Notification tile, it seems as if it is not enabled, but on the configure page, I can see it enabled (see images below).

When I download the build of my app, I can't see anythnig related to Push Notifications. Anyone knows why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Guy, if your push notifications settings are not persisting after choosing "Save changes" and you have a valid .p12 Universal Cert, please post a thread in the AWS Mobile Development forums and we can take a look. Thanks. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=88

Comment: Okay will do, thanks!